# Interate through json data with python

Tags: python, json

I have been working on this code for a few hours trying a bunch of things to iterate through the supplied json data.  Can figure out how to properly iterate through these nested lists and objects.

```
import json

data = """
{
 "tracks": "1",
 "timeline": {
"0.733251541": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "bounds": {
      "Width": 0.5099463905313426,
      "Height": 0.2867199993133546,
      "Y": 0.4436400003433228,
      "X": 0.4876505160745349
    }
  }
],
"0.965": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "bounds": {
      "Width": 0.4205311330135182,
      "Height": 0.2363199994340539,
      "Y": 0.2393400002829731,
      "X": 0.1593787633901481
    }
  }
],
"1.098224": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "bounds": {
      "Width": 0.4568560813801344,
      "Height": 0.2564799993857742,
      "Y": 0.1992600003071129,
      "X": 0.1000513407532317
    }
  }
]
  },
"taggedTracks": {
"1": "dirk"
}
}
"""

json = json.loads(data)

for a in json["timeline"]:
    for b in a:
        for c in b["bounds"]:
            print a, c["Width"], c["Height"], c["Y"], c["X"]
```

Can someone please steer me in the right direction on how to deal with the json data supplied?

I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the the TypeError because inside each value of "timeline", first comes a list. You have to take the first value of that list, using the index of 0. Then you can parse the rest.

Hopefully the following code helps:

```
import json

data = """
{
"tracks": "1",
"timeline": {
"0.733251541": [
{
    "id": 1,
    "bounds": {
    "Width": 0.5099463905313426,
    "Height": 0.2867199993133546,
    "Y": 0.4436400003433228,
    "X": 0.4876505160745349
    }
}
],
"0.965": [
{
    "id": 1,
    "bounds": {
    "Width": 0.4205311330135182,
    "Height": 0.2363199994340539,
    "Y": 0.2393400002829731,
    "X": 0.1593787633901481
    }
}
],
"1.098224": [
{
    "id": 1,
    "bounds": {
    "Width": 0.4568560813801344,
    "Height": 0.2564799993857742,
    "Y": 0.1992600003071129,
    "X": 0.1000513407532317
    }
}
]
},
"taggedTracks": {
"1": "dirk"
}
}
"""

test_json = json.loads(data)

for num, data in test_json["timeline"].iteritems():
    print(num+":")
    bounds = data[0]["bounds"]
    for bound, value in bounds.iteritems():
        print('\t'+bound+": "+str(value))
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's not a great idea to use the name `json` for a variable since that is the name of the module.  Let's use `j` instead.

Anyway, when you do `json.loads()`, you get back a `dict`.  When you iterate `for a in <dict>`, you get back the list of keys (only).  You can instead iterate over the keys and values with `iteritems()`, like:

```
for k, a in j['timeline'].iteritems():
    for b in a:
        c = b['bounds']
        print k, c["Width"], c["Height"], c["Y"], c["X"]
```